# reformatting a text file into CSV format

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, csv

Sample Input

```
0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml "Fruits/Mango Apple /Plum cherry date">1446815.ABC
0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b 5da-0-ba-c1-1a9 "Fruits/Pear Banana/Plum orange mango"
0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b ac-94-4ab-91-23 "Fruits/Pear Banana/Plum orange mango"
0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b 5z-94-ab-92-2f3 "Fruits/Pear Banana/Plum orange mango"

952f-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml "Fruits/Mango"1244115.ABC
3cff-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml "Fruits/Big Mango/Not Sweet ">905499.ABC
6m0k-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml "Fruits/Big Pear/Very Sweet">855499.ABC

17a-42-df-c24.xml "Fruits Market/Big Apple/Sweet "1483415.ABC
17a-42-df-c24 54-ba-4411-9-3d8 "Veg/Radish /Radish Carrot Celery Onion"
17a-42-df-c24 2da5-0-4a-b1-e89 "Veg/Radish /Radish Carrot Celery Onion"
17a-42-df-c24 b7-94-4db-92-2f3 "Veg/Radish /Radish Carrot Celery Onion"
17a-42-df-c24 4d-67c-446-b5-ac "Veg/Radish /Radish Carrot Celery Onion"
17a-42-df-c24 2-8b-4det-87-769 "Veg/Radish /Radish Carrot Celery Onion"
```

Expected Output -

```
0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml,"Fruits/Mango Apple /Plum cherry date",0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b,5da-0-ba-c1-1a9,"Fruits/Pear Banana/Plum orange mango"
0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml,"Fruits/Mango Apple /Plum cherry date",0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b,ac-94-4ab-91-23,"Fruits/Pear Banana/Plum orange mango"
0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml,"Fruits/Mango Apple /Plum cherry date",0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b,5z-94-ab-92-2f3,"Fruits/Pear Banana/Plum orange mango"

952f-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml,"Fruits/Mango",,
3cff-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml,"Fruits/Big Mango/Not Sweet ",,
6m0k-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml,"Fruits/Big Pear/Very Sweet",,


17a-42-df-c24.xml,"Fruits Market/Big Apple/Sweet ",17a-42-df-c24,54-ba-4411-9-3d8,"Veg/Radish /Radish Carrot Celery Onion"
17a-42-df-c24.xml,"Fruits Market/Big Apple/Sweet ",17a-42-df-c24,2da5-0-4a-b1-e89,"Veg/Radish /Radish Carrot Celery Onion"
17a-42-df-c24.xml,"Fruits Market/Big Apple/Sweet ",17a-42-df-c24,b7-94-4db-92-2f3,"Veg/Radish /Radish Carrot Celery Onion"
17a-42-df-c24.xml,"Fruits Market/Big Apple/Sweet ",17a-42-df-c24,4d-67c-446-b5-ac,"Veg/Radish /Radish Carrot Celery Onion"
17a-42-df-c24.xml,"Fruits Market/Big Apple/Sweet ",17a-42-df-c24,2-8b-4det-87-769,"Veg/Radish /Radish Carrot Celery Onion"
```

**In input raw data:**

1. There is no leading and trailing white space in each row.
2. There is no white space among rows. The white space shown is intended to make it look presentable/understandable. White space in final output is not needed either.
3. Symbol ">" is missing in few rows. This is not a typo.

Can you give me direction on how to reformat using bash/shell script (sed, awk etc). I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{
  if (sub(/\.xml /, ".xml,")){      # replace `.xml ` with `.xml,`
    if (NR>1 && is_processed != 1){ # xml line was not printed?
       print xml","                 # print previous xml line + `,`
    }
    sub(/>?[0-9]+\.ABC$/, ",") # replace strings `>1446815.ABC` or `1244115.ABC` with `,`
    xml=$0                     # save line in variable `xml`
    is_processed=0             # clear flag
  }
  else {
    if (!NF) next  # skip empty line
    sub(/ /, ",")  # replace 1st ` ` with `,`
    sub(/ /, ",")  # replace 2nd ` ` with `,`
    print xml$0    # print xml line + current line
    is_processed=1 # set flag
  }
}
END {
  # print possible remaining line
  if (is_processed != 1) print xml","
}' filein > fileout
```

The `if`-block processes the line containing `.xml` and saves it in variable `xml`. The `else`-block processes the following "children" of the xml line and prints the xml line plus the modified line with the first two space characters replaced by a comma. Empty lines are skipped.

If there are no "children", then the xml line with an additional comma is printed in the top `if`-block (if the line number is greater 1) or in the `END`-block.

Output (`fileout`):

```
0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml,"Fruits/Mango Apple /Plum cherry date",0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b,5da-0-ba-c1-1a9,"Fruits/Pear Banana/Plum orange mango"
0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml,"Fruits/Mango Apple /Plum cherry date",0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b,ac-94-4ab-91-23,"Fruits/Pear Banana/Plum orange mango"
0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml,"Fruits/Mango Apple /Plum cherry date",0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b,5z-94-ab-92-2f3,"Fruits/Pear Banana/Plum orange mango"
952f-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml,"Fruits/Mango",,
3cff-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml,"Fruits/Big Mango/Not Sweet ",,
6m0k-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml,"Fruits/Big Pear/Very Sweet",,
17a-42-df-c24.xml,"Fruits Market/Big Apple/Sweet ",17a-42-df-c24,54-ba-4411-9-3d8,"Veg/Radish /Radish Carrot Celery Onion"
17a-42-df-c24.xml,"Fruits Market/Big Apple/Sweet ",17a-42-df-c24,2da5-0-4a-b1-e89,"Veg/Radish /Radish Carrot Celery Onion"
17a-42-df-c24.xml,"Fruits Market/Big Apple/Sweet ",17a-42-df-c24,b7-94-4db-92-2f3,"Veg/Radish /Radish Carrot Celery Onion"
17a-42-df-c24.xml,"Fruits Market/Big Apple/Sweet ",17a-42-df-c24,4d-67c-446-b5-ac,"Veg/Radish /Radish Carrot Celery Onion"
17a-42-df-c24.xml,"Fruits Market/Big Apple/Sweet ",17a-42-df-c24,2-8b-4det-87-769,"Veg/Radish /Radish Carrot Celery Onion"
```

Comment: Big thanks for the answer and the comments in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and sed

```bsh
<input.csv sed -r 's|^(.+")(.?[0-9]+.+)$|\1 "\2"|g' | \
mlr --csv -N --ifs " " put 'if($1=~"xml") {$4=$1;$5=$2}' \
then unsparsify \
then fill-down -f 4,5  \
then count-similar -g 4 \
then filter '($1=~"xml" && $count==1) || ($1!=~"xml" && $count>1)' \
then reorder -f 4,5,1,2,3 \
then put 'if($2=~"Fru"){$1="";$2="";$3=""}' \
then cut -x -f count
```

you will have

```
+------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+------------------+----------------------------------------+
| 0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml | Fruits/Mango Apple /Plum cherry date | 0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b | 5da-0-ba-c1-1a9  | Fruits/Pear Banana/Plum orange mango   |
| 0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml | Fruits/Mango Apple /Plum cherry date | 0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b | ac-94-4ab-91-23  | Fruits/Pear Banana/Plum orange mango   |
| 0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml | Fruits/Mango Apple /Plum cherry date | 0bef-82-46-8a-9a0b | 5z-94-ab-92-2f3  | Fruits/Pear Banana/Plum orange mango   |
| 952f-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml | Fruits/Mango                         | -                  | -                | -                                      |
| 3cff-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml | Fruits/Big Mango/Not Sweet           | -                  | -                | -                                      |
| 6m0k-82-46-8a-9a0b.xml | Fruits/Big Pear/Very Sweet           | -                  | -                | -                                      |
| 17a-42-df-c24.xml      | Fruits Market/Big Apple/Sweet        | 17a-42-df-c24      | 54-ba-4411-9-3d8 | Veg/Radish /Radish Carrot Celery Onion |
| 17a-42-df-c24.xml      | Fruits Market/Big Apple/Sweet        | 17a-42-df-c24      | 2da5-0-4a-b1-e89 | Veg/Radish /Radish Carrot Celery Onion |
| 17a-42-df-c24.xml      | Fruits Market/Big Apple/Sweet        | 17a-42-df-c24      | b7-94-4db-92-2f3 | Veg/Radish /Radish Carrot Celery Onion |
| 17a-42-df-c24.xml      | Fruits Market/Big Apple/Sweet        | 17a-42-df-c24      | 4d-67c-446-b5-ac | Veg/Radish /Radish Carrot Celery Onion |
| 17a-42-df-c24.xml      | Fruits Market/Big Apple/Sweet        | 17a-42-df-c24      | 2-8b-4det-87-769 | Veg/Radish /Radish Carrot Celery Onion |
+------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

**Note**: as input I have used a CSV without any empty lines